# Python dictionary declared without key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

While working with OpenCV in Python I came across these lines of code

```
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)
```

I am curious as to what is happening here, it appears as though a Python dictionary is being populated without keys.  I have searched around and not, as of yet, found any reference to how this works.  Here is the link to the source of this code for context:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html

Specifically what I am asking is "what exactly is happening here?"

Comment: Why not write the same line in your Python shell and check what it does? It would have taken less time than the time it took to write the question over here

Comment: I ended up figuring this out within minutes of posting it.

Comment: But by then it was answered and I could not delete it.

Comment: "I ended up figuring this out within minutes of posting it."  For next time, just wait those minutes before posting anything. It would saved people some time better spent on other questions. Also it might be adequate to at least show your gratiture by accepting one of the answers and vote up any one which you consider valid.

Comment: Will do, thank you.  Some of the answers actually did help enunciate the answer to the point where there is now zero ambiguity on the subject.  And to be fair, I did look extensively last night, apparently I just looked in the wrong places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you feed it an explicit list of key-value pairs, it constructs a dictionary with these key-values. So `dict(checks=50)` results in:

```
{'checks':50}
```

and `dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)` is equivalent to:

```
{'algorithm' : FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, 'trees' : 5)
```

In fact if you feed a function a list of explicitly named arguments, you can obtain them like:

```
def func (**kwargs):
    #...
    pass
```

If you now call `func` with `func(foo=4,bar='a')` then, `kwargs` will look like:

```
{'foo':4,'bar:'a'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
index_params = dict(algorithm = 0, trees = 5)
```

`algorithm` and `trees` are the keys.

The resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
 {'algorithm': 0, 'trees': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> If keyword arguments are given, the keyword arguments and their values are added to the dictionary created from the positional argument. If a key being added is already present, the value from the keyword argument replaces the value from the positional argument.
>
> [...]
>
> To illustrate, the following examples all return a dictionary equal to `{"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}`:
>
> ```
> a = dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)
> b = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
> c = dict(zip(['one', 'two', 'three'], [1, 2, 3]))
> d = dict([('two', 2), ('one', 1), ('three', 3)])
> e = dict({'three': 3, 'one': 1, 'two': 2})
> ```

So your example is equivalent to:

```
index_params = {'algorithm': FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, 'trees': 5}
search_params = {'checks': 50}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative syntax for establishing key, value pairs. For instance, in index_params algorithm is a key and FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE is a value.

Answer (score 0):

There three equivalent ways to construct a dictionary in python:

directly (the most well-known way)

```
data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

from sequence

```
data = dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
```

or from named arguments (only if the keys are strings)

```
data = dict(a=1, b=2)
```

Your example just uses the last approach

Comment: You should explain what keys are considered strings